# How to model falling modelling clay deformation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity

I drop a cylindrical piece of modelling clay/plasticine from the height of 15-20 meters. How can I calculate deformation? The cylinder can fall horizontally, vertically and at angle.

What is the principle - how to calculate force and time duration of that force acting at the moment the cylinder hits the hard earth (pavement, asphalt, concrete)? And what deformation equations to use?

Comment: You would need to develop (i.e., do experiments to measure) the rheological constitutive equation for the clay.  This is the relationship between the stress tensor and the kinematics of an arbitrary deformation.  Possibly, a "Bingham Plastic" rheological model would do the trick.  You would then have to combine this with the differential equation of motion (basically a differential version of Newton's 2nd law involving the velocity vector and the stress tensor).  Problems like this a typically solved using computational fluid dynamics (CFD) software.  It's a complicated problem.

Comment: There will likely not be any analytic solutions in your case, you will have to solve them numerically. There is a fair number of computer graphics papers working on deformable objects - they often use various grid methods solving the elastic deformation equations approximately.

Comment: Is the deformation the end result you are trying to find, or is that an indication of some other property which you are trying to deduce by studying deformation?